# What does the hreflang do when used on link tag?

Tags: html, attributes

I'm reading the documentation of `link` tag at `MDN`.

I read about the `hreflang` attribute, The documentations says:

> This attribute indicates the language of the linked resource. It is purely advisory. Allowed values are determined by BCP47. Use this attribute only if the href attribute is present.

I didn't understand what it does actually, for what is it useful etc... .

I searched in google for solutions, I found some articles about `SEO` and this attribute that say That this attribute helps search engines to server the right page to the user.
What I thought about that is what is the scenario ? if the user searches in english so it should serves him the english version , and if searches in another language so it should serves the another language page? (or maybe with `hreflang` in use it should serves him only one of the pages depending on it's location).

I would like to hear a nice explain about that.

Also , the pages who wrote about `hreflang` and `SEO` described the `link` tag with `rel="alternate"` but in the documentation there wasn't an reference to that relationship, does it useful with stylsheets? if so the should the browser should download the appropiate stylesheet that match the user language?

Answer (score 0):

In the general sense, it describes the locale of the current page + related translations (presuming they have distinct urls).  See [Moz hreflang attribute](https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag).  According to that link, Google & Yandex consume the links, but Bing consumes language meta tags instead.

[Google's hreflang guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) describe how they intend you to create them and how you can target specific locale's (with potentially more targetted urls).